# Get node text on node click TAdvTreeview delphi

Tags: delphi, tms

I am dynamically building nodes in `TAdvTreeview` on create. Based on the type of user, each one sees different number of nodes. I am able to get index of the selected TAdvTreeViewVirtualNode(`ANode.index`) shown to him in the TAdvTreeview by triggering AdvTreeView1NodeClick event. But is there a way to get text on click of a node?

Comment: I don't have TAdvTreeView, but most TreeView controls have a `Selected/Selection` property by which you can get node information e.g. `if TreeView1.Selected <> nil then .. TreeView1.Selected.Text`

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that I don't find  TAdvTreeview text property at all

Answer (score 0):

procedure Tf_AAA.AdvTreeView1NodeClick(Sender: TObject;
  ANode: TAdvTreeViewVirtualNode);
begin
    Edit1.Text := AdvTreeView1.SelectedNodes[0].Text[0];
end;

Comment: Please elaborate the answer, also click on the help button to see the formatting option.